# Solution to USB port not accepting any cables/devices?

Tags: usb, hardware-failure, usb-2

Is there anything that commonly happens with a full-size USB 2 port (female) that can make it impossible to insert any USB cables/devices?

I have a USB 2 port in a laptop that simply won't accept any USB cables/devices.  A male USB connector can be inserted about 1/3 of the way, but then it just stops like it's being impeded by something physical.

I've looked at the port with a magnifying glass, and there is no debris inside.

Any idea what is wrong and a solution to fix it?

---

### UPDATE 1

I noticed that the USB port will allow male USB connectors to be inserted a little more on the left side, than the right side.  This implies that something is impeding access on the right side.  In the photos, there does appear to be a little something on the right side, but it looks like it is part of the female port.  Any idea what we are seeing along the right edge of the port?

### UPDATE 2

I took a thin piece of plastic, about 3mm wide and under 1mm thick, and inserted it around the tongue.  I was able to insert it all the way everywhere above and below the tongue.  I was also able to insert it all the way perpendicular to the left esge of the tongue.

But when trying to insert it perpendicular to the right edge of tongue, it would only go in about half way.  So there's the problem.  But AFAIK, there are no pins along that edge to get bent.

Any ideas what is interfering with insertion and how to fix it?

Photo 1:
[image: USB Port Photo 1]

Photo 2:
[image: USB Port Photo 2]

Photo 3:
[image: USB Port Photo 3]

Comment: Pictures? Sounds like it has to be something sticking out or bent

Comment: @Xen2050 Thank you for your interest.  I will upload photos promptly.

Comment: I've had a similar problem where the tongue become broken / flexible at its base, and unless the plug was inserted perfectly straight, the tongue was pressed into the nearest wall when plugged in.  Unfortunately, the port was a motherboard port and not fixable.

Answer (score 1):

The Tongue in the bottom third of the slot could be broken, allowing the drive to be partially inserted the wrong way.

Comment: I've added some photos to help with your diagnosis and repair suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look bad in your photos, the 4 yellow contact areas don't look like they're sticking down too far, and the top tabs don't look bent, the plastic "tongue" looks ok, it looks a lot like a stock photo of a USB connector:

[image]

The problem sounds like the top tabs would be bent, or a contact is bent or sticking up too far. Some (all?) of the connectors use springy contacts, you could check that all 4 of them move almost flush when they're pressed (upwards).

I can't tell if there's enough space on all the sides for the opposite male USB's "metal box" to get around the plastic tongue. I'd try taking something firm, like a small piece of cut business card or thin plastic card (ice cream pail lid?), and see if it will fit all around the connector - if it gets stuck you've narrowed down the problem, I'm still guessing a bent tab, or foreign object.

Assuming the male USB is good, I don't see what else the problem could be. Just needs space for the "metal box" to go around the "plastic tongue" and the connectors to be flat enough or squish up.